# Write to GCS in parquet format from apache_beam DoFn in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, parquet, apache-beam-io

I am trying to read the Pub/Sub message and write that to a GCS location in parquet format. I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-dataflow#code_sample) code sample in Google documentation to have window and shards added to the file.

Any help with suggestions or code samples will be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

The code of `WriteOneFilePerWindow` is defined [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/common/WriteOneFilePerWindow.java). It uses `TextIO` instead of `ParquetIO`.

You can follow the example to write your own PTransform with `ParquetIO`.
Override the `expand` function to use

```
@Override
public PDone expand(PCollection<String> input) {
  ResourceId resource = FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(filenamePrefix);
  FileIO.Write write = 
    FileIO.<GenericRecord>.write()
        .via(ParquetIO.sink(SCHEMA))
        .to(new PerWindowFiles(resource))
        .withTempDirectory(resource.getCurrentDirectory())
        .withWindowedWrites();
  if (numShards != null) {
    write = write.withNumShards(numShards);
  }
  return input.apply(write);
}
```

You can find doc about `ParquetIO` [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/parquet/ParquetIO.html)